# Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo<T>(), &algorithms)

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow

```
F C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows-gpu\PY\36\tensorflow\core\kernels\conv_ops.cc:717] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo<T>(), &algorithms)
```

Использую Tensorflow 1.5 ввиду отсутствия AVX. Для совместимости использую keras 2.1.5. Cuda toolkit 9.0; cudnn 7.6.5 драйвер Studio 442.92
Драйвера переустанавливал, не помогло

Код модели, если требуется

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(27, 48, 1)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Comment: [здесь](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1064) говорят, что подобная ошибка может возникнуть если у вас запущен еще один интерпретатор Python, использующий GPU ресурсы...